# Select all rows which had a value at least once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which contains songs played in over a period and their position in charts.

The columns are:

```
Date | Position | Streams | Artist | Song | Song ID
```

How can I select all the songs that have been on position == 1, but not limited to just those rows?

My first plan was to retrieve in a dataframe all the songs where position == 1 and later create a new dataset by joining by song_id

is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
top_songs = df[df.Position == 1]["Song"].values
df_selection = df[df.Song.isin(top_songs)]
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.Position==1, 'Song']`